# Google Analytics goal flow regex doesn't work

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking

[Goal Flow screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0bLB.png)

I have a 3 step goal flow set up in GA.

```
Step1: .*\/lvq\/search-(.*)
Step2: .*\/lvq\/search-(.*)\/ask
Destination: .*\/lvq\/search-(.*)\/ask\/thank-you
```

The URLs are:

```
Step 1: www.domain.co.uk/lvq/search-pagename-pagename
Step 2: www.domain.co.uk/lvq/search-pagename-pagename/ask
Destination: www.domain.co.uk/lvq/search-pagename-pagename/thank-you
```

The goal only works for Step 1. After that apparently it's 100% drop off. I know that it's not the case so there must be issue with the Regex.

Comment: Try it like this: 1) `.*/lvq/search-([^/]*)`, 2) `.*/lvq/search-([^/]*)/ask$`, 3) `.*/lvq/search-([^/]*)/ask/thank-you$`

Comment: Hello Wiktor, thanks for your reply. Only step 1 works.

Comment: Why? Maybe we should just remove `$` there? Try 2) `.*/lvq/search-([^/]*)/ask`, 3) `.*/lvq/search-([^/]*)/ask/thank-you`

Comment: Doesn't work either. I even trying adding the backlash to all '/'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the regex for `Step 1` matches your URLs for both Step 1 **AND** Step 2. Therefore, as Google Analytics is concerned, Step 2 never happens, and therefore there will always be a 100% dropoff after Step 1.

You can fix this by tightening your regex:

**Step 1:** `.*/lvq/search\-[a-zA-Z\-]+$`

**Step 2:** `.*/lvq/search\-.*/ask`

**Step 3:** `.*/lvq/search\-.*/ask/thank\-you`

I also made a few edits to your original regex:

- Escaped `-`s
- No need to escape `/`s

Comment: Hello Vinoaj. thanks for your reply. This regex doesn't work at all.

Comment: Did you test it with a new conversion? Changing the funnel step & conversion page rules will only apply to conversions that happen *after* your changes are saved. Previous conversions won't be re-processed with the new rules

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your goal settings?

Comment: I uploaded the link to my original posts. This is including your regex. Goal setup is 'Custom' and Goal Type is 'destination'

Comment: Hmm. Try my modified regex above (changing `\/` to `/`)

Comment: Can you provide some of your actual URLs? It's likely the dummy URLs that you presented don't actually represent all the nuances of the real world URLs